# Iconic Tile BackgroundColor not working when set in WMAppManifest

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

When settings the background color in the WMAppManifest like following example the phone themes color is still used.

The microsoft documentation points out it will only work if the color starts with #FF... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207009(v=vs.105).aspx

> Important Note:
>   If the BackgroundColor element's color value does not begin with #FF, such as #FF524742, your custom background color will not display and the default theme color will display instead.

```
<Tokens>
  <PrimaryToken TokenID="WindowsPhoneApp" TaskName="_default">
    <TemplateIconic>
      <SmallImageURI IsRelative="true" IsResource="false">Assets\Tiles\IconicTileSmall.png</SmallImageURI>
      <Count>0</Count>
      <IconImageURI IsRelative="true" IsResource="false">Assets\Tiles\IconicTileMediumLarge.png</IconImageURI>
      <Title>WindowsPhoneApp</Title>
      <Message>
      </Message>
      <BackgroundColor>#FF016FAC</BackgroundColor>
      <HasLarge>True</HasLarge>
      <LargeContent1>
      </LargeContent1>
      <LargeContent2>
      </LargeContent2>
      <LargeContent3>
      </LargeContent3>
      <DeviceLockImageURI IsRelative="true" IsResource="false">
      </DeviceLockImageURI>
    </TemplateIconic>
  </PrimaryToken>
</Tokens>
```

How to get this working? Is this a known bug?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found the solution. The Microsoft documentation is lacking some information when setting this from the `WMAppManifest`.

As the documentation reads when setting the backgroundcolor in xml you should always start your color with `#FF`.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207009(v=vs.105).aspx

However you should do this when you use an xml file as your tile configuration you should NOT do this in the `AppManifest`. In the AppManifest just specify the color without the Alpha channel, so just `#RRGGBB` and make sure there are no spaces arround or new lines.

Following should be on one line exactly like this.

```
<BackgroundColor>#016FAC</BackgroundColor>
```

When you try to do it like this it will not work:

```
<BackgroundColor>
    #016FAC
</BackgroundColor>
```

Microsoft if you read this please update the docs. It will save a lot of people a lot of researching.

Comment: Yet only worked for me when the app is pinned to start page. In the list of all apps, it still gets the default theme color.

Answer (score 0):

Background property does not work when it declared in the manifest, but will work if you'll set it from the code.

Comment: I tried to avoid setting it from code... This is really strange behavior of the  Windows Phone SDK.

Comment: However, some users report that it can be set [from the manifest](http://codingchick.net/?p=17), check the first comment.